# Data validation for numbers and text together

Tags: excel, validation

How to apply data validation when range is number and text. Column A2: A20 contains text and numbers, data validation does not allow to duplicate entry for numbers and data validation allow to duplicate entry for text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DV with *Custom* **>** *FormulaIs*:

```
=OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(A2)),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,A2)=1)
```